# iPhone - How to partially hide the subview?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am developing one sample application using gestures, where i can pinch, pan and rotate. I have one main image view width and height is 300 and origin x is 0 and y is 70. This imageview I am using from interface builder. After this i am adding one label programmatically on the middle of the imageView. After adding the label I can able to pan, pinch and rotate the label on the view. Now the actual requirement is when i drag the label outside the imageview I should be display the  partial label, for example (My label text is ABCDXYZ). As soon as I drag the Z outside the Z should be invisible, other part ABCDXY should be visible. More clear is drag the one view inside other view. How can i achieve this.

Comment: One easy thing to achieve this is set some appropriate colors to the image view ,label and view so that label become invisible

Comment: @VXtreme i don't want full label to be invisible. only part which is outside the imageview.

Comment: @sachi i think you can reduce the frame size of the label i.e, truncate the part of the label that goeas outside the imageview.

Comment: @SANTHOSH:If my UIView is of white color ,UIImageView is of black color and UILabel of white color then offcourse part of UILabel on UIView will be invisible.

Comment: @VXtreme my uiView has some different color, imageView will be having different image, label background transparent

Comment: @PratyushaTerli how can i truncate.

Comment: @SANTHOSH reduce frame size of the label as it moves outside the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is create a `UIView`. On that add the UIImageView like

```
[View addSubView:ImageView];
```

then add the UIlabel on the UIImageView like

```
[ImageView addSubView:Label];
```

Now set the `clipsToBounds = YES`. I think now your issue of the partial label would be solved as the label would move within the `UIView` and as soon as it goes out it would be shown partially. Any doubt please tell . Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

Its really tricky to give handheld solution for this, instead it could be a suggestion. I assuming that your `UILabel` text is dynamic, there's some scenarios you can follow to achieve this.

1) When you touch your label inside `UIImageView` you shoud get the exact `coordinates` of it.

2) Get the position where user touch on `UILabel`.

3) Compare the touch coordinates with total coordinates of `UILabel`.

4) Assume which character did touched. (You should make test of it, also text size may also matters).

5) When user drag that particular character (say `Z`) you need to remove that from `UILabel` text.

That's all. You're done.